# Subfields and degree of $[K(t):K]$ for a given field $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I came across an example in Stewart's *Galois Theory* wherein we have field $K$ and a simple extension $K\subset K(t)$.

In an example we are asked to find the degree  $[\mathbb{Z}_5(t):\mathbb{Z}_5]$.

Initially I said okay $\mathbb{Z}_5(t)=\{a+ bt:a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_5\}$, and so a basis for the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_5(t)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is $\{1,t\}$ thus the degree $[\mathbb{Z}_5(t):\mathbb{Z}_5]$ is 2. However the answer is "infinite". I then thought that the set describing this field will be a generic combination of powers of $t$?

In another example, we are given the case when $K=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and are asked to describe the subfields of $K(t)$ of various forms, e.g. $K(t^2)$ and $K(t+1)$. I'm not even sure where to start with this!

To summarise my queries: 
Is there anything we can say about a generic extension $K\subset K(t)$? How do you describe the field whenever t is an unknown?
How do we obtain that the degree is infinite? 
How can we go about describing the subfields of such a field (without applying actual Galois theory methods - these are introductory field theory exercises).

Thanks

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_5(t)$ denotes the [field of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) over $\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: The usual "degree" is the degree of an _algebraic extension_. In this case, we are dealing with an _transcendental extension_, since $t$ is not algebraic over $K$.

Comment: How do you know $t$ isn't algebraic? Is it because it is an indeterminate?

Comment: @Natasha Yes...

Comment: Degree is the vector space degree. For instance, you can't write $t^2$ as a $K$-linear combination of $1$ and $t$ so those elements don't give a $K$-basis, and hence the degree is definitely not $2$. You can see that by proceeding in this fashion the degree must be infinite.